# Are there any negative effects from using a generic exception in a catch block

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

If a method throws, say, an IOException, is there any negative effect from doing:

```
catch (Exception ex){

}
```

instead of

```
catch (IOException ex){

}
```

in my Java code?

Comment: With the first approach you'll catch every exception which inherits Exception. If you want to catch only a specific exception, like IOException in your case, then use second approach (by defining that specific exception in catch block).

Comment: You might catch an exception what you don't want to (or better: can't) handle at that point, just at another level. This is not to be overlooked!

Comment: It's poor style.  You'll not just catch `IOException`, but everything that is an `Exception`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course there is / are!

If you catch `Exception`  you will catch all exceptions (apart from instances of `Throwable` or `Error` and it subclasses).  That means that you will catch all sorts of unchecked exceptions, as well as other checked exceptions that you didn't realize could be thrown.

For example:

```
public class Test {
    private File file;

    public String load() {
        try {
            Reader r = new FileReader(file, "UTF-9");
            // read file
            return // file contents
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return "cannot open file";
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the catch of `Exception` hides two (!) bugs in the code.

---

> OK, thanks. I guess I'll just catch all the exceptions individually then.

There is another alternative.  Java 7 allows you to catch multiple exceptions like this:

```
catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    // handle both types of exception ...
}
```

Comment: Errors are not subclasses of Exception, but subclasses of Throwable.

Comment: Says "catch all exceptions except ...". Obviously `catch(Exception e)` catches all exceptions with no exceptions.

Comment: @UMad - if you read the literature, is is conventional to call instances of `Throwable` and *all of its subclasses* "exceptions" with a small "e".  The JLS does, and that's good enough for me.  Instances of `Error` are exceptions that are not caught if you catch `Exception`.

Comment: OK, thanks. I guess I'll just catch all the exceptions individually then.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**
Anything that would end up in the second block would end up in the first. However there is a whole heap of stuff that would end up in the first that wouldn't be in the second; **so in short you catch a whole bunch of exceptions that you didn't intend to**. So yes its a bad idea

**Incorrect fix applied to the wrong problem**
I'm assuming that inside the catch block you have some sort of code to fix or clean up after an `IOException` or at the very least tells the end user what happened (he says hopefully), having this code run for any `Exception` could cause unexpected results. Additionally it could hide an exception you didn't even realise was occurring.

**Debugging difficulties**
Imagine later you alter a piece of code that causes a null pointer exception, or an array out of bounds. And yet it keeps behaving as if an IO problem has occurred. That would be much much harder to debug than if the NullPointerException had just been thrown.

I've already said it, but I'll reiterate; that empty catch block is just for this example right?

Answer (score 0):

IOException is inherited from Exception, so when you do:

```
catch (IOException ex)
```

You are only catching IOException.

But when you do:

```
catch (Exception ex)
```

You are catching all exceptions, including IOException. So you do not know which exception has occurred, this could be called when something other than IOException caused it.
If someone wants to treat all exceptions the same,  catch (Exception ex) could be used, but if one wants to take different actions for different exception types, one should use catch (IOException ex).

Comment: And what is the effect of that? I think that is the insight the question is looking for? Isn't it? Is that bad, is that good, and why?

Answer (score 0):

Both way you can print an error message.  By catching any IOException.
explicitly, you can show custom error message to user like this is error regrading to IO issue or no of other thing related to it like

> Exception handlers can do more than just print error messages or halt the program. They can do error recovery, prompt the user to make a decision, or propagate the error up to a higher-level handler using chained exceptions.

While catching Exception, It catch all general exception not only IOException.

Comment: @SolomonKim No, you should have many catch blocks each with a different "solution" applied within them. A solution could just be telling the end user what happened but could be closing a stream or otherwse correcting the problem. A generic Exception e catch should be a last resort

Comment: Its worth noting that an error message isn't the only thing a catch block can do, sometimes the program can be recovered by using an alternate solution or the catch block can return the program to safe state (regarding streams, save files etc etc)

Answer (score 0):

Some exceptions are used to report programming errors, that's the case of exceptions like

- ArrayIndexOutOfBounds
- NullPointerException
- IllegalArgumentException, etc.

These exceptions are used by programmers to indicate that their API is incorrectly used.

On the other hand there are exceptions that are used to report specific problems and exceptional conditions happening inside an API, like when we get an IOException or an SQLException.

Today, it is customary to use unchecked exceptions for this kind of problems, like the JPA API which uses different unchecked exceptions like PersistenceException.

Now, if you catch all exceptions, then you may end up capturing and handling programming errors along with application exceptional conditions. Programming errors should better be left unhandled to make them evident and fix them and capturing them just hide them.

So, it is best to strive first to capture the most specific exceptions possible.